# Read file that changes regularly

Tags: ruby, file, io

My program reads a configuration file every 3 sec. within a while loop. Once I change the configuration file with an external editor like notepad, my program creates a temporary file for some reason and keeps reading from there.

I want my program to read from the current configuration file in order to have the most recent changes in my program.

What can I do about it?

Simplified code:

```
while(true)
  file = File.open(filename, "r")
  data = JSON.parse(file.read) if file
  file.close
  sleep(3)
end
```

Comment: It is your program. You have to tell why your program creates a temporal file and reads it from there. We cannot help without knowing why that is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on linux, you can try linux [inotfy service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), this is the [gem](https://github.com/nex3/rb-inotify). This is an [example of how to use it](https://github.com/aredridel/ruby-inotify/blob/master/examples/watcher.rb).

First of all you have to run

```
gem install ruby-inotify
```

and then try this code

```
  notifier = Inotify.new
  notifier.add_watch(filename, Inotify::CREATE | Inotify::MODIFY)

  notifier.each_event do |ev|
    file = File.open(filename, "r")
    data = JSON.parse(file.read)
    file.close
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are open to using a gem for this, use the following.

https://github.com/thomasfl/filewatcher

Usage

```
FileWatcher.new(["lib/", "Rakefile"]).watch do |filename|
  puts "Changed " + filename
end
```

Comment: Why would you down vote this? This is essentially what the asker is trying to do... _I want my program to read from the current configuration file in order to have the most recent changes in my program._